# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class in MainActivity

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-jetpack

I'm new to kotlin. I dont know how to fix this error.
I'm getting "Cannot create an instance of abstract class" compile error I'm getting in MainActivity at below line:

> ```
> val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
> ```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))  --->Compile error line
val viewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)

bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
```

**NewsRepository.kt:**

```
 class NewsRepository(val db: ArticleDatabase) {

    suspend fun getBreakingNews(countryCode: String, pageNumber: Int) =
        RetrofitInstance.api.getBreakingNews(countryCode, pageNumber)

}
```

**ArticleDatabase.kt:**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Article::class],
    version = 1
)

@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ArticleDatabase() : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getArticleDao(): ArticleDao

    companion object{
        
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ArticleDatabase? = null
    }

    private val LOCK = Any()


    operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance?: synchronized(LOCK){


          instance ?: createDatabase(context).also{ instance = it }

    }

    private fun createDatabase(context: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
            ArticleDatabase::class.java,
            "article_db.db").build()


    override fun createOpenHelper(config: DatabaseConfiguration?): SupportSQLiteOpenHelper {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun createInvalidationTracker(): InvalidationTracker {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun clearAllTables() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


}
```

Edit: Added the full code for ArticleDatabase class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code `invoke` function inside the companion object to fix this issue.

```
abstract class ArticleDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getArticleDao(): ArticleDao

    companion object{
        
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ArticleDatabase? = null

        private val LOCK = Any()


        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance?: synchronized(LOCK){
          instance ?: createDatabase(context).also{ instance = it }

    }

    }

    private fun createDatabase(context: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
            ArticleDatabase::class.java,
            "article_db.db").build()


    override fun createOpenHelper(config: DatabaseConfiguration?): SupportSQLiteOpenHelper {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun createInvalidationTracker(): InvalidationTracker {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun clearAllTables() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) tutorial on how to use Room properly

You need to actually create database instance

```
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            ArticleDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        ).build()
```

And then inject it to the repository

```
val newsRepository = NewsRepository(db)
```

Comment: Please check edited class name article database. I have created db already

Comment: Ok, then you need to pass the created db to NewsRepository, not create it again